# How to fix the colours of the Spectrum with Numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So far I have written a code that through which I was able to create a spectrum.

Here's the code:

```
def draw(self):
        x = np.linspace(0, 1, self.resolution)
        y = np.linspace(0, 1, self.resolution)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        R = X
        G = Y
        B = np.ones_like(X) * 0.5
        print(R,G,B)
        self.output = np.stack([R, G, B], axis=-1)
        return self.output.copy()
```

But it's giving me a spectrum with light colours:
[Current spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIMoh.png)

But I want to create an Image like this:

[Required spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZoxp.png)

Any help would be appreciated or if you can recommend where I can learn about this fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You add 0.5 to the blue color channel everywhere, while in your target image the amount of blue fades from left to right.

```
def draw(self):
        x = np.linspace(0, 1, self.resolution)
        y = np.linspace(0, 1, self.resolution)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        R = X
        G = Y
        B = X[:, ::-1]
        print(R,G,B)
        self.output = np.stack([R, G, B], axis=-1)
        return self.output.copy()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok this is working now - could you please share the resources where I can learn more on this?